# nginx showing default page on wan but not lan

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04

When I access my nginx webserver on lan, it shows me the correct webpage I have setup. For some reason when I try to connect to it through a different network, it returns the default nginx page. It is still able to connect, it just displays the wrong page.

How would I fix this issue so it shows the webpage on both lan and wan? Port forward on my router is functional and is not the issue. The connection goes through a cloudflare proxy, could this be the issue?

Here is my configuration file:

```
server_tokens off;

server {
listen 80;
server_name <domain>;
if($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http"){
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name <domain>;

root /var/www/pterodactyl/public;
index index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/pterodactyl.app-error.log error;

# allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_timeout 120s;

sendfile off;

# SSL Configuration
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# See https://hstspreload.org/ before uncommenting the line below.
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; preload;";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have your CloudFlare SSL setting set to Full or Full (strict) (recommended). Flexible or Off will not work.